# The straight line $y = m(x – a)$ will meet the parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ at two distinct real points for which values of $m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> The straight line $y = m(x – a)$ will meet the parabola $y^2  = 4ax$
>   at two distinct real points for which values of $m$?

The answer is given as $m \in \mathbb R - {\{0\}}$.

I tried to solve by using the method of discriminants as follows:

$\{m(x-a)\}^2=4ax$, and then putting $D>0$, I get $1+m^2>0$ which is true for all reals.

I can't understand why $m=0$ can't be true from the result I get using the discriminant method. Any ideas ?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I know that (by intuition) . But why isn't the discriminant method showing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if we have a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then the solution is given by:
$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$

*Hence, the solution implicitly assumes that $a \neq 0$, which is the assumption that the equation is exactly of second degree and no less*.

Now, let us look at the equation $m^2(x-a)^2 = 4ax$. This expands to:
$$
m^2x^2 - 2m^2xa + m^2a^2 = 4ax \implies m^2x^2 +x(-4a-2ma) + ma^2 = 0
$$

Hence, your discriminant evaluates to $m^2+1$, which is greater than zero, *for all applicable $m$*. We have already seen that $m \neq 0$ is not applicable for this situation, because in the general quadratic solution, $m$ appears *in the denominator*, hence if $m=0$ we will be *dividing by zero, which is a problem*.

At $m=0$, the equation is not quadratic, and there is only one solution. Hence, it follows that there are two solutions on $\mathbb R - \{ 0\}$.

Comment: even if it is not quadratic,how could you tell it has only one solution?

Comment: Because when $m=0$ the equation changes to $-4ax = 0$, which shows that $x=0$ is the unique meeting point of the parabola and the line, unless $a=0$ in which case the two concide.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0\ (\color{red}{a\not=0})$ is $D=b^2-4ac$.

In our case, we have
$$m^2x^2+(-2am^2-4a)x+m^2a^2=0$$
For $m=0$, we have $-4ax=0$ which is not a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

$$
y^2=4ax
$$
So we just need $a \ne 0$ to have a parabola. Otherwise there would be no possibility to have the intersection with a line be two distinct points.

For the intersection we got the system
$$
y = m (x - a) \\
y^2 = 4ax
$$
we note $m \ne 0$ is needed for two intersection points, otherwise we would only have $x=0, y=0$ as solution. For $m \ne 0$ we have
$$
4ax = m^2(x-a)^2 = m^2(x^2 -2 ax + a^2) \iff \\
0 = x^2 - 2ax + a^2 - (4a/m^2) x \\
= x^2 - 2a(1 + 2/m^2) x + a^2  \\
= (x - (1+2/m^2)a)^2 - (1+2/m^2)^2a^2 + a^2 \\
= (x - (1+2/m^2)a)^2 - (4/m^2 + 4/m^4) a^2 \\
= (x - (1+2/m^2)a)^2 - (4/m^2)(1+1/m^2) a^2 \iff \\
(x - (1+2/m^2)a)^2 = (4/m^2)(1+1/m^2) a^2 \iff \\
x = (1+2/m^2)a \pm (2/m)\sqrt{1+1/m^2} a 
$$
This gives no new constraint for $m$. We just need $m \ne 0$.